# Problem with ajax call, json returns error 500

Tags: c#, json, ajax

I am trying to return an object / list of objects in Json format to my webpage. When I return it as an object or List of objects I get error code 500. Request URL: localhost:"portnumber"/Home/FindCustomer Request Method: POST Status Code: 500 Remote Address: [::1]:"portnumber" Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade.
When I debug my code I see that the controller returns the List or object filled with data (not null) however the view side cannot parse it properly, I have read a similar post regarding circular references however I dont know if that is causing the problem

Customers class (6 fields - firstname,lastname,address,phone1,phone2,email) extends BasicObj class (1 field - type Guid - Oid)

this is the controller-side code

```
     List<Customers> cusList = new List<Customers>();

        try
        {
            using (UnitOfWork uow = XpoHelper.GetNewUnitOfWork())
            {
                CriteriaOperator crit = CriteriaOperator.And(new BinaryOperator("firstname", "test", BinaryOperatorType.Equal));
                Customers cust = uow.FindObject<Customers>(crit);
                cusList.Add(cust);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Error");
        }

        if (cusList.Count == 0)
        {
            return Json(null);
        }

        else
        {
            //return Json(cusList);   doesnt work, causes error 500
            //return Json(cusList[0]);   also doesnt work, same error 500

            //return Json(new
            //{
            //    Oid = cusList[0].Oid,
            //    firstname = cusList[0].firstname,
            //    lastname = cusList[0].lastname,
            //    address = cusList[0].address,       this way it works
            //    phone1 = cusList[0].phone1,
            //    phone2 = cusList[0].phone2,
            //    email = cusList[0].email
            //});

        }
```

this is the view code (I have commented the for-loop where I can access the list contents one by one)

```
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result != null) {
                console.log(result);

                $('#customerTable tbody').empty();
                //for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    $("#customerTable").append('<tr><td>' + result.firstname + '</td><td>' + result.lastname + '</td><td>' + result.address + '</td><td>' + result.phone1 + '</td><td>' + result.phone2 + '</td><td>' + result.email + '</td><td>' + result.Oid + '</td></tr>');
                //}

            }
            else {
                $('#customerTable tbody').empty();
                alert("Customer not found");
            }

        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Go check the error log to find out what the actual error is.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see what's going on?

Comment: Request URL: https://localhost:"portnumber"/Home/FindCustomer
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: [::1]:"portnumber"
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

When I debug my code I see that the controller returns the List or object filled with data (not null) however the view side cannot parse it properly, I have read a similar post regarding circular references however I dont know if that is causing the problem

Comment: This is a problem between your server and your browser. Did you configure any CSP rules?

Comment: if I implement my database without using XPO it works just fine, list gets returned from the controller and printed in the view just fine. Converting the db to using XPO messes it up